# ffmpeg: test if format is seekable

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, libavformat

How do i test if a format is seekable?

I have written code against the latest fmmpeg's (4.4) libavformat, libavcodec, etc. My code reads and decodes video files. Now i also want to support reading from avdevices, such as dshow (DirectShow) on Windows. That is possible through the same interface as i have already implemented, it just requires using the dshow format. Super nice! But in my video file reader, i have some seek logic implemented, which is engaged in various instances. The problem is that the dshow format is not seekable (`avformat_seek_file()` returns -22, invalid argument). **How do i detect that a format is not seekable?** I know that the `AVFormatContext`'s `pb` member (`AVIOContext`) has a `seekable` field, but the dshow format leaves `pb` null (as it should be since the `AVFMT_NOFILE` flag is set for the format). How do i test if a format is seekable (so that if it is not, i can disable the seek logic)? The implementation of `avformat_seek_file()` and the various functions it calls seems to have various callbacks, so i am not sure if simply this would do the trick: `bool isSeekable = !!context->pb && context->pb->seekable!=0`.

Comment: I was trying to find a proper way to check if seek is available as well. I think you should check context->iformat (AVInputFormat) flags and read_seek/read_seek2 [doxygen](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structAVInputFormat.html#a1b30f6647d0c2faf38ba8786d7c3a838)

Comment: Thanks, that would make sense. Indeed i have seen formats with a null pb, but which are still seekable (I think it was an image sequence). I have read the code, if read_seek and read_Seek2 are both null, but the AVFMT_NOGENSEARCH flag is not set, seek will try the generic method. That seems to fail as well for my dshow source (which has no flags set except AVFMT_NOFILE). Perhaps that is a bug/oversight.

Comment: Possible another way, trying to execute the avseek* function and see if you get an error of 'operation not permitted'. However, I have noticed that some hls are allowing seek but i get that error even there. Not sure how I could seek on those.

Comment: Thanks, i think your first suggestion is correct. It seems that by oversight the noseek flags are not set on this input format. I'll take it up on the ffmpeg list